# Data binding in Angular UI - is it push or pull? Can I make it faster?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I have a variable `a` and it is rendered in html as `{{a}}` and then I change its value in typescript `a = "new value";`, how fast the new value appears in the UI ?

Is there a timer which checks all the bound variables and renders them if they have changed? or is there a code which renders value in a setter somewhere?

How do I make the binding work faster?

Comment: This may help in understanding Angular's change detection: https://angular.io/guide/zone.  Here you can find information on the new DevTools feature that helps you profile your application during change detection:  https://angular.io/guide/devtools. Also, there is an `OnPush` change detection strategy you can use to improve performance if your components use `@Input` OR bind to Observables with the async pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanic behind this is called **change detection**.

You can read more about it in various articles like https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/.

> How do I make the binding work faster?

There is no general response to this, it really depends on your code logic. You'll have to profile your app to see the potential bottlenecks.